# Should I be able sync a local Wakanda Git with a Remote Server?

Tags: git, wakanda

Have not been able to sync a local Git repository with a remote server (running same version of Wakanda). Tried with v10 and v1.1.1.

Old docs (v5) indicate this was possible... but have not seen any documentation suggesting it can be done now. It appears you can only use the built-in Git to sync with GitHub.  Is this correct?

I would like to sync the same local Git repository with multiple remote Wakanda Servers.

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: At the moment, I cannot recall. Are you saying I *should* be able to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm saying you are asking people to help you out of the graciousness of their hearts, so the least you can do, to show them some respect and appreciation, is give them as much information as you can.

Comment: Mort, no disrespect intended... whatsoever. I simply was asking if it *should* work with the described setup. I really don't know what error I was receiving... as it has been a few months since I attempted. Before taking another shot (with extreme time constraints), I thought I would ask if Wakanda is currently designed to use Git in this fashion. If it *is*, I will attempt again... and if I still have problems, I will probably post an implementation question. Is that not an acceptable use of Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can synchronize your local repository with multiple remote repositories ([source](https://wakanda.github.io/wakanda-studio/version-control.html)). Every time you commit a modification you have to push each modification to each remote using the Wakanda Studio Git extension (as you would do by command line using git).

*From Wakanda Studio documentation:*

> ... When you expand the Repositories section, the Remote Repositories section appears so that you can create a new remote repository.
>   When you click on the  button, the following fields appear for you to create a new repository:
>
> [image: doc image]

*Note:* This works with the `web` part of your Wakanda project. As you know the Wakanda stack is composed by different parts. However if your aim is to synchronize the database on different machine this doesn't come out of the box. Database replication is a complex problem on every system.